# Why wont Coda 2 save passwords for ftp access?

Tags: web, passwords, save, definition, coda

I have recently switched to Coda 2 on Mac (OSX 10.8.2) and under site definitions the host, username and all other information save fine. It will not, however save my passwords. I DO NOT have "ask each time" checked (preemptive answer). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution for this. If you open up Keychain Access, find the key that is named after your site so for example ftp.sitename.com. Double click it and go to access. Make it so that any program can use it. Then if you go back to Coda, enter the password once and d/c. It should be saved when you re-open the program :)

Comment: Excellent workaround… functioned just as you described. I feel like that is a fault on Panic's behalf. A bit of a timely workaround (moreover if you work on lots of different sites often) but is FAR better than having to remember and supply credentials constantly. Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Great! But the only thing is missing, that you didn't mention how or from where to open KeyChain access. I used mac spotlight to find it. 
Actual location to open Keychain access: under Applications > Utility > KeychainAccess

Just select the ftp.yourwebsiteurl.com
Doubleclick on it
There will be two tabs. Click on AccessControl tab
Select the radio button option : Allow all applications to access this item. 
It will ask your system admin password to allow.

Go back to Coda > right click on your website > click Disconnect
Now reenter your password > Connect.

That's it. Your password will be remembered for further connections.

Answer (score 0):

Coda 2.x has built in FTP, git, SSH, and more.

Coda's way of dealing with FTP is to have you set up your files as a "Site"

Once you set it up this way, it saves FTP logins, git logins, ssh logins, etc for all aspects of that site.

Do this:

1. Open Coda - Coda should automatically open at the 'sites' page. If not, press Command-1 to go to sites.
2. Right-click, and select 'add site'.
3. Fill out the details for the site, and save.
4. Whenever you open that site, Coda will automatically connect to the server.

It's pretty easy to walk thru the dialog options.